# make if statements look better

Tags: c#, if-statement

How can I make this look better:

```
lblTotalWorldSize.Text = GetDirectorySize(_worldsDirectory + selectedItem) * 1024 + " kb";    // Total world size
if (Directory.Exists(_worldsDirectory + selectedItem + "\\" + selectedItem))                  // World itself
{
    lblWorldSize.Text = GetDirectorySize(_worldsDirectory + selectedItem + "\\" + selectedItem) * 1024 + " kb";
}
else
{
    lblWorldSize.Text = "Couldn't find world.";
}
if (Directory.Exists(_worldsDirectory + selectedItem + "\\" + selectedItem + "_nether"))      // Nether
{
    lblNetherSize.Text = GetDirectorySize(_worldsDirectory + selectedItem + "\\" + selectedItem + "_nether") * 1024 + " kb";
}
else
{
    lblWorldSize.Text = "Couldn't find world.";
}
if (Directory.Exists(_worldsDirectory + selectedItem + "\\" + selectedItem + "_the_end"))     // The End
{
    lblTheEndSize.Text = GetDirectorySize(_worldsDirectory + selectedItem + "\\" + selectedItem + "_the_end") * 1024 + " kb";
}
else
{
    lblWorldSize.Text = "Couldn't find world.";
}
```

It really looks like a mess and I can't seem to find any questions like this.

Comment: Is the assignment to `lblWorldSize` in *every* `else` a mistake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, there are several things that can help here:

- A helper method (you're performing the same conversion from "path" to "size string" each time)
- The conditional operator
- Extracting a common local variable

Something like this:

```
// Note that _worldsDirectory must be an absolute path)
string prefix = Path.Combine(_worldsDirectory, selectedItem, selectedItem);
lblWorldSize.Text = GetDirectorySizeOrDefault(prefix, "Couldn't find world");
lblNetherSize.Text = GetDirectorySizeOrDefault(prefix + "_nether",
                                               "Couldn't find _nether");
lblTheEndSize.Text = GetDirectorySizeOrDefault(prefix + "_the_end",
                                               "Couldn't find _the_end");

...

static string GetDirectorySizeOrDefault(string directory, string defaultText)
{
    return Directory.Exists(directory)
        ? GetDirectorySize(directory) * 1024 + " kb"
        : defaultText;
}
```

Note that I've corrected the fact that your original code *always* assigns to `lblWorldSize.Text` on error - I assume that wasn't deliberate.

Comment: Like making a function that can check each folder?

Comment: I see! This sure makes it look better. BTW, if I do it the other way (how I'm doing it right now) will it be slower compared to your way? Jsut curious

Comment: I'm not sure whether to be mad that you posted essentially the same answer as me, before me, or to be happy that I thought of the same answer as Jon Skeet :)

Answer (score 2):

*Please* use `Path.Combine` for path creation, and not string concatenation like you do.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that this method does more than 1 things? You could refactor this in a few other methods maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use intention and variable substitution to enhance readability:

```
string dir = "_worldsDirectory + selectedItem";
string dirItemPath = @"_worldsDirectory + selectedItem \\" + selectedItem;

// Total World Size
lblTotalWorldSize.Text = GetDirectorySize(_worldsDirectory + selectedItem) * 1024 + " kb";

// World itself
if (Directory.Exists(dirItemPath)) {

    lblWorldSize.Text = GetDirectorySize(dirItemPath) * 1024 + " kb";
} else {

     lblWorldSize.Text = "Couldn't find world.";
}

// Nether
if (Directory.Exists(dirItemPath + "_nether")) {

    lblNetherSize.Text = GetDirectorySize(dirItemPath + "_nether") * 1024 + " kb";
} else {

    lblWorldSize.Text = "Couldn't find world.";
}

// The End
if (Directory.Exists(dirItemPath + "_the_end")) {

    lblTheEndSize.Text = GetDirectorySize(dirItemPath + "_the_end") * 1024 + " kb";
} else {

    lblWorldSize.Text = "Couldn't find world.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lblTotalWorldSize.Text = GetDirectorySize(_worldsDirectory + selectedItem) * 1024 + " kb";    // Total world size

DoOnDirectoryExists(lblWorldSize, "");    
DoOnDirectoryExists(lblNetherSize, "_nether");    
DoOnDirectoryExists(lblWorldSize, "_the_end");    


//Change the name to something more appropriate to your program, same with the LBL type and tempString
public bool DoOnDirectoryExists(LBL lbl, string suffix)
{
    string tempString = _worldsDirectory + selectedItem + "\\" + selectedItem + suffix;

    if (Directory.Exists(tempString))     
    {
         lbl.Text = GetDirectorySize(tempString) * 1024 + " kb";
    }
    else
    {
        lblWorldSize.Text = "Couldn't find world.";
    }
}
```

Best way to get rid of clutter and make your code more readable - remove code duplication.